# Unresolved attribute reference 'batch_create_jobs' for class 'JobServiceClient'

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-api-services-jobs

I am following the example in the how-to guide for batch operations in Google's Cloud Talent Solution service found [in this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/talent-v4beta1-samples/jobs/v4/job_search_list_companies.py)

I have tried all the other examples and they are working fine.

Except this one, where I get the following error.

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'batch_create_jobs' for class 'JobServiceClient'
```

The IDE is also complaining and unable to auto complete the missing function.

My code boils down to this:

```
from google.cloud import talent_v4beta1

client = talent_v4beta1.JobServiceClient()
# initialize jobs and parent variables
operation = client.batch_update_jobs(parent, jobs) # this line is failing
```